# Can't get int BIOS on Windows 11

Tags: windows, bios, windows-11

For some reason I can't get into setup menu to enter into BIOS. Pressing DEL/ESC/F2 keys during reboot does't work. System -> Recovery -> Advance startup -> Restart didn't work.
Read somewhere that monitor may be an issue. I'm not sure about that. I've LG monitor, driver is Intel Generic PnP. There isn't any driver available for this model, installing the LG driver available doesn't have any impact.

How do I get into BIOS? MSI Z690 is the MB.

Comment: According to the user's manual the key is DEL, not ESC or F2. Please always read the manual before making assumptions.

Comment: Choosing Advanced Startup absolutely should have worked. The only other way is to force Windows to fail to boot three times.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, tried DEL too.

Comment: May be it is issue with monitor, may be it shows setup screen but monitor is not able to show? I don't see anything on monitor during reboot, It just shows login screen as first thing on monitor. Dies it give any clue?

Comment: Have you tried hold shift then choosing reboot? If nothing shows on the monitor, what do you do at that point, hard reset?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is because your system has both an integrated GPU and a discreet GPU, and the integrated GPU is being used for BIOS.

Change your display connection to use the integrated graphics by using a display connector that's integrated into the motherboard. It will be near the USB ports in the back of your system. I would suggest changing the BIOS setting to prefer the discreet GPU. Exactly how to do this varies by motherboard. Look for a setting like "IDG Multi Monitor" and disable it. Or look for a setting that prefers dGPU or PEG.

If there is no such port, it could be that UEFI is initializing display on another discreet GPU. Or if you have only one discreet GPU (most likely) the currently utilized port isn't intializing for some reason, such as an incompatible DP to HDMI adapter. Try another port or a different type of adapter (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

The problem, indeed, was monitor as I was thinking all along. My monitor was connected to integrated graphics. In the last moment I connected monitor to 3090 HDMI port and problem was resolved. I'm not sure why monitor doesn't show setup screen when connected to onboard graphics?

Comment: The issue isn't the monitor, it's the GPUs. Some BIOS (typically enterprise systems, so servers or workstations) will gracefully switch between integrated and discreet GPUs, most consumer motherboards will not.

If you prefer to use the integrated (e.g. you're using the dGPU for compute, otherwise you're likely better served by using the dGPU instead), ensure that any IDG Multi Monitor setting is enabled, and that your BIOS is set to prefer on-board, integrated, or IGP graphics. Although the settings are related to booting, changing the boot order won't achieve the desired result.